# Android ellipsize does not work properly

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm building a new InfoWindow (google maps api v2) and I'm trying to get my layout to be perfect.
A part of that layout is this:

```
  <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/txtInfoWindowName"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:ellipsize="end"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:textColor="#ff000000"
  android:textSize="14dp"
  android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/txtInfoWindowObstacles"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:ellipsize="end"
  android:maxLength="32"
  android:lines="1"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:textColor="#ff7f7f7f"
  android:textSize="14dp"/>
```

Now, the problem is with the `android:ellipsize="end".`
It should draw the three dots at the end but it doesn't do that.
Now I'm getting something like this:

```
TextTextTextTextTe
```

Instead of this:

```
TextTextTextTextTe...
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that I'm using layout_width="wrap_content" . But I need that because I'm using a LinearLayout

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried your code and they work fine, except the second TextView which has the attribute `android:maxLength="32"`, which in this case the text cannot be ellipsized because of 32 characters limit. But if you remove it, it works as expected.

Comment: that was acctually the TextView I was refering to. But I want this one to show about max 32 characters. So if it's more, it will stop at 32 and print 3 dots. How can I do that?

Comment: You can't do that. What you can do is to set a fixed width instead of `"wrap_content"`, for example: `android:layout_width="100dp"`, and remove the maxLength attribute.

Comment: That would work fine, but I want the layout to stay as small as possible. So if there would be only 4 characters in it, you don't have all of that blanc space to the left and right...

Comment: I see. Then lets try this one: add a new attribute: `android:maxWidth="100dp"`, remove `maxLength`, and have `layout_width="wrap_content"`. It should trigger ellipsize, and do not leave blank space.

Answer (score 3):

There is another option - you can format your string from code like this:

```
private static final int STR_MAX_CHAR_COUNT = 32;

private String formatString(String stringToFormat) {
    if(stringToFormat.length() > STR_MAX_CHAR_COUNT){
        stringToFormat = stringToFormat.substring(0, STR_MAX_CHAR_COUNT - 1) + "...";
    }
    return stringToFormat;
}
```

And then just set string like this:

```
String newText = "some long-long text";
mTextView.setText(formatString(newText))
```